# Kubernetes: Kubectl still pointing to Minikube after removal

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I had Minikube installed on my Mac and then I removed it and replaced it with a [3-node cluster using Multipass and K3s](https://medium.com/better-programming/local-k3s-cluster-made-easy-with-multipass-108bf6ce577c). Now my issue is that `kubectl` is still referring to Minikube when I execute its commands in terminal.

For instance when I run `kubectl get nodes` I get the following error:

```
Error in configuration: 
* unable to read client-cert /Users/hemodd/.minikube/client.crt for cluster1 due to open /Users/hemodd/.minikube/client.crt: no such file or directory
* unable to read client-key /Users/hemodd/.minikube/client.key for cluster1 due to open /Users/hemodd/.minikube/client.key: no such file or directory
* unable to read certificate-authority /Users/hemodd/.minikube/ca.crt for cluster1 due to open /Users/hemodd/.minikube/ca.crt: no such file or directory
```

I have followed these steps to remove Minikube but I am still getting the same error:

```
minikube delete 
brew uninstall minikube
rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error are mostly about the wrong setting in kubeconfig, please double  check local file `~/.kube/confg`

This is the default kubectl configuration file, it includes three parts: clusters, contexts and users

If you have two kubernetes clusters (one is minikube, and the other is k3s), you should be fine to set up them in same file without conflict.

Read this first: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

Each cluster should have related certificates (and user certificates) set properly.

then you are fine to set the current context with below command

```
kubectl config set-context XXXX
```

Answer (score -3):

**Uninstall minikube on MacOS**

These are the following Steps

```
minikube delete
rm /usr/local/bin/minikube
rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

Comment: ~/.minikube contains generates certificates for minikube node. ~/.kube/config contains the contexts of the kubernetes cluster. You may delete/change the current context with the command kubectl config delete-context or set-context